# Create dictionary from points list and multiple attribute lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to create a dictionary of this format:

```
mydic = {
    0: {'a': (20,10), 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 
    1: {'a': (0,10), 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 
    2: {'a': (4,5), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
    3: {'a': (6,2), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
    4: {'a': (1,4), 'b': 0, 'c': 1} 
}
```

Given four lists:

```
node = [0,1,2,3,4]
a = [(20,10),(0,10),(4,5),(6,2),(1,4)]
b = [1,0,0,0,0]
c = [0,1,0,0,1]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/ you are welcome

Comment: Why is the `1` key different then the rest? Seems like that comes out of nowhere. Also, do you have any attempted solutions? Please post what code you have tried.

Comment: Typo sorry, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If the iterables are all the same length, you can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) with a *dict comprehension*:

```
items = node, a, b, c
result = {n: {'a': a_, 'b': b_, 'c': c_} for n, a_, b_, c_ in zip(*items)}
# {0: {'a': (20, 10), 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 1: {'a': (0, 10), 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, 2: {'a': (4, 5), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 3: {'a': (6, 2), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 4: {'a': (1, 4), 'b': 0, 'c': 1}}
```

Which can also be written like this:

```
items = node, a, b, c
keys = 'a', 'b', 'c'
result = {x[0]: dict(zip(keys, x[1:])) for x in zip(*items)}
```

You could probably also use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) here:

```
items = node, a, b, c
keys = 'a', 'b', 'c'
result = dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], dict(zip(keys, x[1:]))), zip(*items)))
```

Comment: @tobias_k Hmm, what would you rather do here instead?

Comment: I just don't like "shadowing" the list by using the same name again. In older versions of Python, this may even "leak" out of a list comprehension, i.e. `a` would be an element of `a` afterwards (not from dict-comps, though, as it seems). Why not use `for a_ in a` or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your lists are all the same size, you just can loop through each index and create the key/value pair for each entry in the dict:

```
node = [0,1,2,3,4]
a = [(20,10),(0,10),(4,5),(6,2),(1,4)]
b = [1,0,0,0,0]
c = [0,1,0,0,1]

assert(len(node) == len(a) == len(b) == len(c))  #Length should be equal

mydict = dict() # init empty dict

# Loops from 0 to len(node)
for i in range(len(node)):
    entry = {'a': a[i], 'b': b[i], 'c': c[i]}  # Creates dict object matching format
    mydict[node[i]] = entry  # Sets dict as value for each node item

print(mydict)
```

This outputs:

```
{
  0: {'a': (20, 10), 'b': 1, 'c': 0}, 
  1: {'a': (0, 10), 'b': 0, 'c': 1}, 
  2: {'a': (4, 5), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
  3: {'a': (6, 2), 'b': 0, 'c': 0}, 
  4: {'a': (1, 4), 'b': 0, 'c': 1}
}
```